# Como tirar as virgulas e inserir espaços entre os números deste array?

Tags: javascript

Fiz este array mas não consigo tirar as vírgulas e trocá-las por dois ou três espaços. Alguém tem uma ideia para me ajudar se faz favor?

```
<div id="demo1" name="demo1" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top:25px;color:red; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;  letter-spacing: 00px;">   
<script>

var arr = []
while(arr.length < 4){
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*16) + 1;
    if(arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
}
document.write(arr);

</script>
</div>
```

EXEMPLO DO RESULTADO:
3,12,9,7

RESULTADO PRETENDIDO COM 1 OU MAIS ESPAÇOS:
3 12 9 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a função `join(caracterSeparador)` para adicionar o caracter separador entre cada item do array.

Exemplo:

```
var arr = [];

while (arr.length < 4) {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*16) + 1;

    if (arr.indexOf(r) === -1) 
        arr.push(r);
}

// 1 espaço em branco
document.write(arr.join('&nbsp;'));
```

Se quiser 3 espaços, basta colocar como parâmetro na função `join`:

```
// 3 espaços em branco
document.write(arr.join('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'));
```

Como está utilizando a função `document.write` o conteúdo será escrito no HTML, por esse motivo o espaço em branco é o caractere `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Obrigado mas só consegui colocar 1 espaço.. não consigo 2 ou 3 espaços?

Comment: Tente novamente, com essa alteração da resposta.

Comment: Exactamente.. é isso mesmo. Eu fico muito agradecido.

Comment: Se a resposta te ajudou e pode ajudar outras pessoas marque-a como resposta aceita por favor. Obrigado :D

Comment: Ok.. Eu cliquei na marca de verificação e passou à cor verde.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Para unirum array em uma string use a função `join` passando o caracter que será usado entre os elementos:

```
[1, 2, 3].join(' ');
```